# Create a VM with a reserved IP

Tags: azure

I tried to create a VM with a reserved IP adress like this:

New-AzureQuickVM -ImageName a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201409.01-en.us-127GB.vhd -ServiceName VmPIPBis3 -Windows -AdminUsername amethyste -Location "West Europe" -Password SuperMotDePasse12 -ReservedIPName 104.45.13.146

But all I get is this error message:

New-AzureQuickVM : BadRequest: The Reserved IP 104.45.13.146 does not exist.

The only thing created is the service cloud

Does anybody know what happened?

thanks

Comment: Did you call New-AzureReservedIP and/or Get-AzureReservedIP first in order to determine that you own the IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first reserve the IP in your Azure Subscription and then pass the ReservedIPName (not the address) to the **ReservedIPName** parameter in your call to New-AzureQuickVM.  Below is a script that creates a new reserved IP if one doesn't exist for the name given and then creates a new VM using the reserved IP.

```
$location = "West US"
$appVMName = "AppVM01"
$appVMServiceName = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
$imageName = "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201409.01-en.us-127GB.vhd"
$adminUser = "AdminUser"
$adminPswd = "AdminPassw0rd"
$reservedIPName = $appVMName + "-resrvdIP"

# Get the reserved IP if it exists or create a new one.
$reservedIP = Get-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName $reservedIPName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($reservedIP -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Reserving IP in '$location' as '$reservedIPName'."
    New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName $reservedIPName -Location $location
    $reservedIP = Get-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName $reservedIPName -ErrorAction Stop
}

# Create a new VM using the reserved IP
New-AzureQuickVM -Name $appVMName -ServiceName $appVMServiceName -Windows -ImageName $imageName `
  -AdminUsername $adminUser -Password $adminPswd -Location $location -ReservedIPName $reservedIP.ReservedIPName

Write-Host "VM Created using the following reserved IP Address:... " + $reservedIP.Address
```

Comment: thank you your are right and I feel a little bit stupid!